# mysql query problem WHERE date < 

Tags: mysql

i have following query

```
SELECT *, count(jx_commissions.commission_amount) AS summe 
FROM jx_members 
INNER JOIN jx_commissions ON jx_commissions.mid = jx_members.mid 
WHERE jx_commissions.date > '2011-01-01'
GROUP BY jx_commissions.mid 
ORDER BY summe DESC 
LIMIT 1, 20
```

field Date have a date format and all dates have the right format Y-m-d

but if i use this query i do not get any results... if i change date to a nother one, i get wrong results... i think he compare a string... but how can i search for a date??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks okay - if `date` is a date field, this will do a date comparison. Can you show what kind of wrong results you get?

Comment: if i use date from 2010-09-01 i get reuslt also from 2010-08-xx maybe even lower...

Comment: the problem was LIMIT 1,20... i had only one result.. so i have to use 0, 20...

Comment: It looks like the same trap as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897133/mysql-select-date-range-issue/4897195#4897195).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `jx_commissions.date` is a date field you can just do a conditional like `jx_commissions.date > DATE('2011-01-01')`

Comment: I just did it in my DB. What exactly are you trying? I think you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you do a non identifiable export of your database and show us on http://pastebin.com/?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hHBt46SC here is this table... but no Data... there some sensible data :) i hope you can help me...

Comment: Checkity check it. I made this http://pastebin.com/1twyJhVB from your structure and insesrted four items with dates from the 26th-29th. If you run a query like "SELECT * FROM `jx_commissions` WHERE `date` > DATE('2011-01-27')" you only get the 28th and 29th. I thought it was maybe because you had "date" and not "`date`" but my tool doesn't care. Let me know if this helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert the column into a true date.

```
SELECT *, count(jx_commissions.commission_amount) AS summe 
FROM jx_members 
INNER JOIN jx_commissions ON jx_commissions.mid = jx_members.mid 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(jx_commissions.date, '%Y-%m-%d') > '2011-01-01'
GROUP BY jx_commissions.mid 
ORDER BY summe DESC 
LIMIT 1, 20
```