# MySQL select date range issue

Tags: mysql

I'm getting some strange results from using BETWEEN in my sql query. Wondering if anyone can help me to understand why i am getting these results.

I'm searching a date range in the format of dd/mm/yyyy. So i want to select all entries within a certain date range.

```
$dbSearchRecords_result = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Date BETWEEN '$DateFrom_order' AND '$DateTo_order'";

$dbSearchRecords_result = mysql_query($dbSearchRecords_result);
```

I am then calling the results in a while statement from an array

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dbSearchRecords_result)){
```

Now if I search BETWEEN 12/02/2011 14/02/2011 there is a date returned from 13/12/2010.

Yet if I search 12/02/2011 13/02/201 I do not get the result of 13/12/2010.

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your date variables are actually formatted as proper dates?

Comment: Have you checked that the generated SQL statement from PHP is what you expected?

Comment: @ KeenLearner. I've only just realized that which is pretty silly of me. I'm pretty sure that is the main issue. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `BETWEEN`operator is most likely reading your ranges as strings. [From the book:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

> For best results when using BETWEEN
>   with date or time values, use CAST()
>   to explicitly convert the values to
>   the desired data type. Examples: If
>   you compare a DATETIME to two DATE
>   values, convert the DATE values to
>   DATETIME values. If you use a string
>   constant such as '2001-1-1' in a
>   comparison to a DATE, cast the string
>   to a DATE.

So, try:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN CAST('2011-01-02' AS DATE) AND CAST('2011-12-02' AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 5):

MySQL's needs values in this format to do a proper comparison:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

you could use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to convert your string into the right format.

Plus obviously, the `Date` field needs to be of the `DATE` or `DATETIME` type.

Answer (score 1):

try to format the values as DATE.. as in

```
$dbSearchRecords_result = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Date BETWEEN DATE('$DateFrom_order') AND DATE('$DateTo_order')";
```