# Select a date range (Month/Year) in database

Tags: mysql

I have a quick question regarding selecting dateranges in MySQL, formatted like this `YYYY-MM-DD`

I read [MySQL select date range issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897133/mysql-select-date-range-issue) and understand the basic usage of it, but how can I "include" the 29th of february for example? I'd like to avoid a PHP workaround, is there anything like that in MySQL?

I can't quite understand http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

can someone give me an example how to select last years data from february?

Comment: please give us some data and desired result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The moment you specify a month, MYSQL engine is smart enough to get the correct number of days for a month (whether it's a leap year or not) and evaluate your date fields accordingly.

To get data between two dates of your choice: (using `interval -1 year` to get one year back from today)

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable 
WHERE yourdate BETWEEN DATE_ADD(Now(), Interval -1 YEAR)
AND Now() 
AND MONTH(yourdate) = 2 -- to get data for Month of February
;
```

Or you can simply just write with YEAR function without `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable 
WHERE YEAR(yourdate) = YEAR(Now()) - 1
AND MONTH(yourdate) = 2 -- to get data for Month of February
;
```

For the question on [`Str_to_Date`](http://www.w3cyberlearnings.com/Mysql_STR_TO_DATE) the function is used to convert string that contains a date into a date type with a desired format and it's the inverse of `DATE_FORMAT` function.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('12-Apr-2012', '%d-%M-%Y')
FROM DUAL
;
```

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO FOR LEAP YEAR 2012](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c600d0/4)

Notice in the above demo that you have to specify the day, month, year arrangement in the format you are adding into the `STR_TO_DATE` function.

- [Reference on MYSQL Site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
- [You may also look into `DATE_FORMAT` to format a date type field into a desired date format.](http://www.w3cyberlearnings.com/Mysql_DATE_FORMAT)

PS: it's rather vague what you are really tryhing to achieve here, without sameple data and expected reslts shown in the question.. :)

Comment: @PrimusS do take a look at the information and samples given here then comment please if you need further help. But really, if you can show some sample data of your own, that's great =)

Comment: You can add that if you want an index on `yourdate` to be used effectively by the query, it should be written as `WHERE yourdate >= '2012-02-01' AND yourdate < '2012-03-01'` (with no functions applied on the `yourdate` column)

Comment: +1 @ypercube that adds upto the performance and sharply specific on `date range` :)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for... Meaning the YEAR and MONTH functions in MySQL. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3):

Below query will give you data of last year February month

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table_name` WHERE YEAR(`your_date_field_name`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND MONTH(`your_date_field_name`) = 2
```