# Date range between two date columns

Tags: mysql

I have these two columns:

```
start_dt                  end_dt
2013-09-18 14:00:00       2013-09-18 16:00:00
```

I want to select the rows between these two dates (stored as datetime in MYSQL), so...

```
SELECT *
FROM task_schedule_times
WHERE `start_dt` >= "2013-09-18 14:00:00"
AND `end_dt` <= "2013-09-18 16:00:00"
```

This is fine, but I need to be able to return the above row if searching for any dates within start_dt and end_dt:

"2013-09-18 **15:00:00**"
and
 "2013-09-18 **15:30:00**"

Visual representantion (the line represents a time interval):

```
entry1: -----------------
select:     ---------
```

I also need to return the row if the date range supplied falls anywhere within range of the row

```
entry1: -----------------
select:     ----------------------
```

or

```
entry1:          -----------------
select: -----------------
```

No results should be displayed in a case like so:

```
entry1:        -----------------
select: -------
```

Hopefully these creative inputs explain things better than I can with words.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL select date range issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897133/mysql-select-date-range-issue)

Comment: @DevlshOne That question is about one column between two dates, it doesn't involve comparing two columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for overlapping periods of time.  Two periods overlap when one *starts* before the other *ends* and the first *ends* after the second *starts*:

```
SELECT *
FROM task_schedule_times
WHERE `end_dt` >= "2013-09-18 14:00:00" AND
      `start_dt` <= "2013-09-18 16:00:00"
```

Answer (score 3):

The `entry start` should be always `<=` of `select end`

The `entry end` should be always `>=` of `select start`

```
SELECT *
FROM task_schedule_times
WHERE `start_dt` <= "2013-09-18 16:00:00"
AND `end_dt` >= "2013-09-18 14:00:00"
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `task_schedule_times`
WHERE (`start_dt` BETWEEN "2013-09-18 14:00:00" AND "2013-09-18 16:00:00")
OR (`end_dt` BETWEEN "2013-09-18 14:00:00" AND "2013-09-18 16:00:00")
```