# Get records in database by year and month

Tags: php, mysql, date

What I have here is a dropdown's that selects records from database by year and month. This works correctly getting year and only 1 month. What I need is get all Januanry to June records or July to December by year. Help?

My date format is yyyy-mm-dd

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<?php
$startYear = 2013;
$curYear = date('Y');
    echo'<select name="year">';
    foreach (range($startYear, $curYear) as $year) {
    echo '<option>'.$year.'</option>';
    }
    echo'</select>';

    echo'<select name="month">';
    for ($x=1; $x<=12; $x++)
    {
    $val=strlen($x);
    if($val==1)
    {
    echo '<option value="'.'0'.$x.'">'.'0'.$x.'</option>';
    } else {
     echo '<option value="'.$x.'">'.$x.'</option>';
    }
    }
    echo'</select>';
?>
<input type="submit" name="date" value="date"/>
</form>

<?php
    $year = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["year"]);
    $month = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST["month"]);

    echo $year.'-'.$month;
    $result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT po_date, rfq, shop, nego, shop, po_number, counter FROM purchase_order WHERE po_date LIKE '$year-$month-__' GROUP BY counter ORDER BY po_date");
```

Comment: What is the type of "po_date" field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL select date range issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897133/mysql-select-date-range-issue)

Comment: @FezVrasta type is date

Comment: Ok so follow the answer I've linked

Comment: @FezVrasta but how the value of my dropdown?

Comment: Do you mean to say that if found between jan-to-jun then omit jul-to-dec, or retrieve all?

Comment: @Ravinder retrieve all record between jan to june and jul to dec

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch records for a specific month and year, use `month` and `year` functions on the date field.

```
WHERE Year( po_date ) = $year
 and ( Month( po_date ) between 1 and 6    -- for JAN to JUN
       OR
       Month( po_date ) between 7 and 12   -- for JUL to DEC
     )
```

And the statement

```
Month( po_date ) between 1 and 6    -- for JAN to JUN
OR
Month( po_date ) between 7 and 12   -- for JUL to DEC
```

is equivalent to

```
Month( po_date ) between 1 and 12    -- for JAN to DEC
```

And hence you should not use both between conditions.
Instead change the lower and upper boundary values of between clause as desired.

**Example 1**:
If you want records between `april` and `august`, both inclusive, try

```
Month( po_date ) between 4 and 8    -- for APR to AUG, both inclusive
```

**Example 2**:
If you want records within a specific month, say, 'october', try

```
Month( po_date ) = 10    -- for OCT
```

If you still want to use `between` for a single month output, try

```
Month( po_date ) between 10 and 10   -- for OCT
```

Comment: My answer too is in MySQL. It won't affect your data, because it is only a `select`.

Comment: Please don't use your answer to ask for clarification, it can be quite confusing. That's what comments are for.

Comment: @Ravinder would mine to explain it?

Comment: @user3097736: If you want to retrieve records for the 1st or 2nd part of the year, use just that peroid in the `between` clause. i.e. use either `month(po_date) between 1 and 6` or `month(po_date) between 7 and 12 )`.

Comment: @Ravinder I tried it but it get the whole records per year.

Comment: @Ravinder Whatever I chose month, it gets all records. I trying to create a new dropdown that has a value of 01 to 06 or 07 - 12

Comment: It should not. Please read [*my previous comment*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451199/get-records-in-database-by-year-and-month/21451493#comment32489142_21451493). You should fetch *any one of* but not *both of* between conditions.